# selecting an element randomly from the array all combination

Tags: arrays, matlab

I randomly selected elements of an array by matlab code. I selected 8 elements from array(1,64) . Now, I want to create all combination . Example array=[1 2 3 4 ... 64] I randmly selected 8 elements new=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ] new=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 ]...  new is all combination. How can I create all combination? for matlab code

Comment: er, uh, *how* did you randomly select the 8 elements?

Comment: array=[1 2 3 ... 64];msize = numel(array);
idx = randperm(msize);
rndmarray=array(idx(1:8));  
final=sort(rndmarray)       @SamB   this is how ı choise randomly 8 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming order is not important (that is, `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]` don't count as different combinations `[1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7]`), use

```
combinations = nchoosek(1:64,8);
```

But it may take much time and RAM.

For example,

```
>> combinations = nchoosek(1:5,3)
```

gives

```
combinations =

     1     2     3
     1     2     4
     1     2     5
     1     3     4
     1     3     5
     1     4     5
     2     3     4
     2     3     5
     2     4     5
     3     4     5
```

---

To  randomly generate just one of those combinations, without having to compute them all previously:

```
combination = sort(randsample(1:64,8));
```

Comment: thanks for interesting this problem @Luis Mendo. Can we do this with doing genetic algorithm . because  ı have busy station in matlab with  combination = sort(randsample(1:64,8))

Comment: @user3210485 I'm not really into genetic algorithms, sorry